# Returning a Promise inside of a "then" handler causes another unrelated Promise to be resolved with the returned Promise's resolution value

Tags: javascript, promise

I've been trying to figure this one out and I'm wondering how the resolution value gets passed too `getAnswer`'s `then` call. First I `return` the result of `add` which I think returns a Promise which allows me to use a `then` call on the `then` method on `getAnswer`, but then how does the second `return` statement get passed to it?

```js
 function add(num1, num2) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {resolve(num1 + num2);}, 500)

  });
}

function getAnswer() {
  return add(5, 5).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("How does this get passed too getAnswer's then function?");
    });
  });
}

getAnswer().then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "How does it get passed on" - Answer: In the a functions arguments - just like demonstrated in your code (see `res`)

Comment: I'm not understand how the second return statement (return new Promise((resolve, reject) ) is getting passed onto the .then

Comment: Thats just the way promises work....

Comment: "*First I `return` the result of `add`*" - no, you don't. You return the result of `add(…).then(…)`.

Answer (score 1):

**The Basics:**

`add` returns a Promise -- which is an instance of the `Promise` object, every instance of `Promise` has a `then` method which you can use to observe that promise's resolution.
For chaining purposes, `then` has been designed in such a way that it returns a Promise itself (so, every `then` call in JavaScript will always return a new promise). The promise returned by `then` will be resolved with the return value of its handlers (more on this later).

Now, when you say:

```
  return add(5, 5).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("How does this get passed too getAnswer's then function?");
    });
  });
```

You are not returning `add`'s result, you are returning the promise that you created by calling `then` on `add`'s result (this is just standard JS behavior).

**Your Question:**

> but then how does the second return statement get passed to it?

Here is what the `then` method returns, according to MDN (the parts inside `([])` are my additions):

> A Promise in the pending status *([this is what your first `return` statement is actually returning])*. The handler function (onFulfilled or onRejected) gets then called asynchronously *([the handler in your example is the function you've passed to the `then` inside `getAnswer`])*. After the invocation of the handler function, if the handler function:
>
> - returns a value, the promise returned by then gets resolved with the returned value as its value;
> - throws an error, the promise returned by then gets rejected with the thrown error as its value;
> - *([this is your case -- your second `return`])* returns an already resolved promise, the promise returned by then gets resolved with that promise's value as its value;
> - returns an already rejected promise, the promise returned by then gets rejected with that promise's value as its value.
> - returns another pending promise object, the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by then will be subsequent to the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by the handler. Also, the value of the promise returned by then will be the same as the value of the promise returned by the handler.

*Personally, whenever I see a Promise being returned by `then`'s handlers, I just assume -- to simplify the situation for my mind -- that the Promise returned by `then` originally has been replaced with the Promise that was just returned by one of `then`'s handlers. Of course, this mental mapping is parallel to the actual functionality, AFAIK.*

So, to sum it up:

1. `getAnswer` returns a promise -- created by `add(5, 5).then(...)`.
2. you then observe that returned promise using `then` (`getAnswer().then(...)`) -- unrelated here, but this call also creates a promise.
3. it happens that the handler for the observation of the promise returned by the `add` call (this handler is the function you pass to `then` in #1) returns a promise as well, and the rules are that if a handler of `then` returns a promise `p`, then whenever `p` is resolved with a value `v`, the original promise -- created by `then` -- will be resolved with `v` as well.
4. Finally, the handler you passed to the `then` in #2 to observe the promise returned by `getAnswer()` will be called with the value `v` from #3.

---

Feel free to ask for any clarifications, but before doing so, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) article thoroughly.